# Interpreting Lasso regression p-values versus coefficients

Tags: r

I'm wondering how I should interpret a lasso regression's output. Take for example:

```
library(lasso2)
lm.lasso <- l1ce(mpg ~ . , data=mtcars)
summary(lm.lasso)$coefficients
```

The output is:

```
              Value  Std. Error     Z score   Pr(>|Z|)
(Intercept) 36.01809203 18.92587647  1.90311355 0.05702573
cyl         -0.86225790  1.12177221 -0.76865686 0.44209704
disp         0.00000000  0.01912781  0.00000000 1.00000000
hp          -0.01399880  0.02384398 -0.58709992 0.55713660
drat         0.05501092  1.78394922  0.03083659 0.97539986
wt          -2.68868427  2.05683876 -1.30719254 0.19114733
qsec         0.00000000  0.75361628  0.00000000 1.00000000
vs           0.00000000  2.31605743  0.00000000 1.00000000
am           0.44530641  2.14959278  0.20715850 0.83588608
gear         0.00000000  1.62955841  0.00000000 1.00000000
carb        -0.09506985  0.91237207 -0.10420075 0.91701004
```

If I understand right, a lasso regression is supposed to basically minimize features that aren't that important to the model so their coefficients are essentially zero. That makes sense for the `qsec`, `vs`, and `gear` features. However, the p-values are all pretty insignificant.

If I have a coefficient that's basically zero, but the p-value is close to 1, which value should I trust? Should I discard the feature from the model since it's coefficient is zero, or discard it from the model since its p-value is insignificant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The null hypothesis is that the variable coefficient is equal to Zero and has no effect on the model. In order to reject the null hypothesis, you need to have a p-value lower than .05, the smaller the value, the greater you confidence in REJECTING the null hypothesis.

So in evaluating a p-value if the value is 1.00, that means that there is NO CONFIDENCE in the rejection of the null hypothesis (that it is a zero influence coefficient).

So in your model, where the regression dropped the coefficient to zero, with a p-value of 1 it supports your understanding of how the lasso reduces the non-influencing values to a zero coefficient. You should trust both the zero and the one!